# phpdoc datatype and namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, phpdoc

What is the current status of using namespaces in phpdocs datatypes.

eg:

```
* @param string|Vendor\SomeClass $parameter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpDocumentor, at least, doesn't seem to support namespaces yet.

See [this bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2861606&group_id=11194&atid=111194) on its bugtracker, for instance -- it's quite recent : 2009-09-18